# Use parent slot variables in Vue template slot

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs-slots

I have a simple `FormComponent`:

```
<template>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <slot />
    </fieldset>
    <span v-if="!isEditing" @click="edit()">Edit</span>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      isEditing: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    edit (state) {
      this.isEditing = !this.isEditing
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And when I use the component:

```
<FormComponent>
  <input value="Man" type="text" :disabled="!isEditing">
</FormComponent>
```

The input field are correctly slotted into the component but the `:disabled="!isEditing"` from the slot isn't reacting to the change of `isEditing` in the `FormComponent`.

The Vue documentation is pretty good, but it doesn't cover each edge case.

Comment: Please link the documentation part that states this kind of using bindings on slotted elements is supported.

Comment: It asks "how do you know this is even supported".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The component with the `<slot></slot>` tag has to bind the data onto an attribute on the `<slot>` tag, like a prop:

```html
<slot :isEditing="isEditing"></slot>
```

Then when you render that slotted component, Vue creates and exposes an object containing all of the bound data, with each attribute having a property on that object.

Access the object by adding an expression to the `v-slot` directive in this format:

```html
<FormComponent v-slot:default="slotProps">
```

(Or use the alias `#` as in `#default="slotProps"`.)  You can access individual properties like `isEditing` via that object, like `slotProps.isEditing`:

```html
<FormComponent #default="slotProps">
  <input value="Man" type="text" :disabled="!slotProps.isEditing">
</FormComponent>
```

Here's the more common (and versatile) `<template>` syntax:

```html
<FormComponent>
  <template #default="slotProps">
    <input value="Man" type="text" :disabled="!slotProps.isEditing">
  </template>
</FormComponent>
```

You can also [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) `slotProps` for more direct access to the properties:

```html
<FormComponent>
  <template #default="{ isEditing }">
    <input value="Man" type="text" :disabled="!isEditing">
  </template>
</FormComponent>
```

Comment: Could you explain how `#default="{ isEditing }"` works? I understand I need to bind the `isEditing` to the `<slot>` in the component but I don't see the connection between a shorthanded named slot and the `:disabled="!isEditing"`.

Comment: It's just es6 object [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), not a Vue feature.  You may substitute `{ }` for any given object reference, and list the properties you want pulled out.  So `{ }` is a substitute for `slotProps` in the previous example.  There was an object being passed there either way, and now instead of naming it, it's been destructured.

Comment: Yea okay, I got that, sorry. I meant what does the `slotProps` do. I don't understand why it works when you add that to the `FormComponent`. Linking to a good source is also fine, but I can't get it out of the Vue docs why this works.

Comment: It's an object Vue creates which aggregates all the attribute bindings on the `<slot>` tag, so because there is an `isEditing` attribute on the `<slot>`, the property also exists on that object.  The reason `default` is needed is because a name must be given to specify the slot being targeted.  And "default" is the default name of a slot when no name is explicitly given like `<slot name="myslot"></slot>`

Comment: The Vue guide's [slot props doc](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Destructuring-Slot-Props) discusses some of this